# Example of *.wks file for PowerPC64le arch

Tags: yocto, powerpc, ppc64le

List of default WIC files in Yocto toolchain doesn't contain wks file for PowerPC architecture.
Actually I'd like to have configuration for qemuppc64.
Google gives nothing.
Any ideas about direction for futher investigation.